# WPF Fire event for dynamically added control in stack panel

Tags: c#, wpf

I am adding adding a radio button to stack panel for each item in List and that happens without issue. (it adds 4 or 6 radio buttons as those would be count of items in my list).

```
foreach (var nearestgage in nearestgages)
{
     StackPanel.Children.Add(new RadioButton { Content = nearestgage.GageSize.ToString(), Margin = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1) });                        
}
```

Now what i want to do is when any of these dynamically created radio buttons are selected at run time.
I want to fire a event.
So what i am thinking is i will have to attach a handler to my radio button click . I tried a few methods but not able to that. I have another radio button in the grid which does not belong to this group as well. Please suggest what would be the ideal way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a little sample, adding the event to the radio button when it's generated.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <StackPanel Name="StackPanel">

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

C#

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
            rb.Content = "Item " + i.ToString();
            rb.Click += rb_Click;
            StackPanel.Children.Add(rb);
        }
    }

    void rb_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((sender as RadioButton).Content.ToString());
    }
}
```

To deal with keeping the radio button actions separate, set the group name:

```
rb.GroupName = "Dynamic";
```